# Can a QComboBox display a different value than whats in it's list?

Tags: qt, qt5, qcombobox

Using Qt 5.9 on Linux, I have a QComboBox with several labels.

```
qc = new QComboBox;
qc->addItem(tr("Red"));
qc->addItem(tr("Green"));
qc->addItem(tr("Blue"));
```

Lets say a user activates the QComboBox and the 3 color labels are shown in the drop down list. The user then selects the 1st item (red).

What I want to do is have the QComboBox display a different value than what was selected. I.e., if red is selected, then a number is shown, possibly 1 for the first item (or it could be an R for Red), and if green is selected, then display 2 (or G) for the second item.

My goal in doing this is to use less display space (less wide) than is actually necessary to show the complete text of the selection because some of my item strings are quite long and a much shorter label is desired when the QComboBox is not activated in it's drop down state. Besides, the item strings are descriptive and abbreviations would work better for displaying.

**Edit:**
Using Marek's example, thought this might help. Here's what I have. I'm expecting if the user selects from the list, then an R, G, or a B should be displayed after.

```
QStandardItem *red = new QStandardItem();
red->setData(tr("Red"), Qt::DisplayRole);
red->setData("R", Qt::UserRole);

QStandardItem *green = new QStandardItem();
green->setData(tr("Green"), Qt::DisplayRole);
green->setData("G", Qt::UserRole);

QStandardItem *blue = new QStandardItem();
blue->setData(tr("Blue"), Qt::DisplayRole);
blue->setData("B", Qt::UserRole);

QStandardItemModel *rgb_model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
rgb_model->setItem(0, red);
rgb_model->setItem(1, green);
rgb_model->setItem(2, blue);

QComboBox *rgb_cb = new QComboBox();
rgb_cb->setModel(rgb_model);
```

I get the feeling it's because I don't quite understand how to use Qt::UserRole.

Comment: Can you update me about this? I am trying this approach and the value used is still the one I put as DisplayRole.

Comment: @ArchitJ, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63323959/5366641

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. `QComboBox` uses data model to manage items.
You have to provide own data model, with items with respective data values.

```
QStandardItem *itme1 = new QStandardItem();
item1->setData(tr("Red"), Qt::DisplayRole);
item1->setData("1", Qt::UserRole); // note doesn't have to be a string.

QStandardItem *itme2 = new QStandardItem();
item2->setData(tr("Green"), Qt::DisplayRole);
item2->setData("2", Qt::UserRole);

QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
mode->setItem(1, item1);
mode->setItem(2, item2);

qc->setModel(model);
```

It should work, but I didn't test it. At least this should be some clue.

Please review [QComboBox documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#details), especially about roles.

---

Another solution is use translations with multiple lengths. You can provide couple translation for a single string. Each translation should be graphically shorter than earlier one.

In such situation `QString` contains all possibilities separated by spatial character. When such string is rendered first substring (between separators) which will fit available space will be used.

Now I do not remember what is the separator value. I've used this very long time ago (with Qt 4.8) and now can't find reference for it.

Comment: Hint: `QComboBox` alreay has default `QStandardItemModel`. So it is possible to use `auto model = qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>( qc->model() );`

Comment: Minus the typos, I've put that in, but having issues with the UserRole value being displayed as the selected value. It all works with the exception that the DisplayRole ["Green"] is the selected value and the drop down list is the DisplayRole ["Green"] value as well. Just not seeing the UserRole value as the selected value in the normal non-drop down state.

Comment: Still having issues with this. Would appreciate any thoughts anyone might have. Can't get the user role to display in the normal (non-drop down) state.

Comment: @Ender, why did you accept this answer? Did it work for you?

Comment: Why is this accepted and upvoted? It is, at best, an incomplete step in the right direction. How would you make the text area to use one role, and the dropdown use another role? The linked documentation doesn't mention how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

In your example for make it short just make:

```
qc->setWidth( 20 );
```

But  if you really want user choose something, then:

connect( qc, SIGNAL( onCurrentIndexChanged( int ) ), SLOT( changeComboText() ) );
[...]

```
void changeComboText()
{
   QString shortText;
  //Determine short value for shortText
   qc->setCurrentText( shortText );
}
```

Comment: Too ugly. This solution will force emitting a lot of unnesessary signals. Espesically text change signal. And it will not work with editable combobox.

Comment: Just use qc->blockSignals( true ) before and "false" after.  In that case.

Comment: Most nice solution will make colored items without text. But that will much more complicated.

Comment: `blockSignals` really? Another crutch. Colored items are easilly made with roles of model.