# How to show selected text different from list text in QComboBox?

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I have a `QComboBox` with a popup list (a `QAbstractItemView`) showing different items (`QStandardItem`s). Now, I want the item in the list to show a different text than if the item is selected.

**Background:**

I am creating a word-processor like style chooser where one can choose, say, "1.1 Heading 2" from the list, indicating the numbering and the style name, but when an item is chosen the combobox should only show the style name, say "Heading 2".

I thought the following question was exactly about what I was asking for but apparently an answer was chosen that does not work (apparently even according to the person asking the question): [Can a QComboBox display a different value than whats in it's list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47935876)

Answer (score 4):

### Solution

Since `QComboBox` uses a list view to display the values, probably the "Qt'iest" way to achieve the desired effect, is to use a custom delegate and modify the text within its [`paint`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint) method, using a hash map ([`QHash`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html)) to get the corresponding string.

### Example

Here is a simple example I have prepared for you to demonstrate how the proposed solution could be implemented:

**Delegate.h** *this is where the magic is happening*

```
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QApplication>

class Delegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Delegate(QObject *parent = nullptr) :
        QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {}

    void setHash(const QHash<int, QString> &hash) {
        m_hash = hash;
    }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        if (!index.isValid())
            return;

        QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;

        initStyleOption(&opt, index);

        opt.text = m_hash.value(index.row());

        QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &opt, painter);
    }

private:
    QHash<int, QString> m_hash;
};
```

**MainWindow.h** *only for demo purposes*

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include "Delegate.h"

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QWidget(parent)
    {
        auto *l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        auto *cmbBox = new QComboBox(this);
        auto *model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
        auto *delegate = new Delegate(this);
        QHash<int, QString> hash;

        for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
            // For demo purposes I am using "it#" and "item #"
            // Feel free to set those strings to whatever you need
            model->appendRow(new QStandardItem(tr("it%1").arg(QString::number(n))));
            hash.insert(n, tr("item %1").arg(QString::number(n)));
        }

        delegate->setHash(hash);

        cmbBox->setModel(model);
        cmbBox->setItemDelegate(delegate);

        l->addWidget(cmbBox);
        resize(600, 480);
    }
};
```

### Result

The example produces the following result:

[image]

Comment: Note: at this point you can just as well use different item roles (like in the other question) and get those with `QModelIndex::data`, instead of maintaining that `QHash`.

Comment: @YakovGalka, yes, it is possible to implement it like that as well.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do is to set the ComboBox as editable and then when the current item changes, you change the text to whatever you want. Example:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QStringList a = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
    aModel.setStringList(a);
    ui->comboBox->setModel(&aModel);
    ui->comboBox->setEditable(true);
}

void MainWindow::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    if (arg1 == "Green") {
        ui->comboBox->setCurrentText("Green on");
    } else if (arg1 == "Red") {
        ui->comboBox->setCurrentText("Red on");
    }
}
```

`ui->comboBox->setCurrentText("Green on");` will only change the text when the item is selected, when you reopen the combobox, the text will be reverted back to original. This is somewhat similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62602050/2279422).

Another way to do this would be to inherit the `QComboBox` class and then reimplement the `mousePressEvent` to change the model whenever the mouse is pressed, and switch it back after releasing. This will probably be more difficult to get right or may not even work as I have not tried it myself

Comment: It does not make much sense to allow the text of a combo box to be edited in this case, since all entries should be known in advance.

Comment: Exactly. And making it editable, you also allow the user to enter text into it. Which, as already mentioned, does not make much sense. Especially for the UX.

Comment: Not to mention the unnecessary emission of signals.

Comment: You have a point. I agree. Emission of signals isn't much of a problem though. I like your solution,, though it involves a bit more work.

Comment: Well, to be honest, your solution was the first thing I've tried, hence I believe, that it is much more intuitive. However, it has gotchas, which I think should be pointed out. You know, for future reference. Apart from that, I regard both approaches as different ways to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, but my solution is more of a brute force way lol

Comment: :) Though neigher of those would be necessary, if QComboBox offered it out of the box. But the live would be too easy in this case, I suppose. :)